# Internal JSON-RPC error when swapping from ethers.js on uniswap

Tags: swap, web3js, ethers.js, uniswap

I spend a lot of time trying to understand where is the mistake.

I try to swap USDC to any token on uniswap router v3 with ethers.js on frontend.

I use Polygon network in app and in metamask too.

I have a confirmation in my metamask to approve USDC, but after it I have no confirmation about swapping. I see an error in console:

inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. code: -32603 data: code: -32000 message: "execution reverted"

This is my code:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);

const send_account = await provider.getSigner().getAddress();  //my address

//Swap from USDC to MTS or any other token

addressOfUSDC='0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174' // Address of USDC in Polygon
const ERC20Contract = new ethers.Contract(addressOfUSDC, ERC20ABI, provider);
swapRouterAddress="0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564"; //Uniswap v3 router
indadr="0x440416D85E5D51424da371297E3d7Ef28312BF62"; //Any token address to which I want to swap

approvalAmount=12; //12 USDC

await ERC20Contract
    .connect(provider.getSigner())
    .approve(swapRouterAddress, approvalAmount*1000000)

//After this step we see confirmation to spend 12$ in metamask

bn=ethers.BigNumber.from(approvalAmount*1000000); //BigNumber from approvalAmount


const params = {
    tokenIn: addressOfUSDC,
    tokenOut: indadr, 
    fee: ethers.BigNumber.from(3000),  
    recipient: send_account,
    deadline: ethers.BigNumber.from(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 10)),
    amountIn: bn,
    amountOutMinimum: ethers.BigNumber.from(0),
    sqrtPriceLimitX96: ethers.BigNumber.from(0),
}

const UniswapContract= new ethers.Contract(swapRouterAddress, ERC20ABI2, provider);

dd=await UniswapContract
    .connect(provider.getSigner())
    .exactInputSingle(params)

console.log(dd);
```

And after this step I have no confirmation in metamask and error in console: MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. execution reverted

Maybe the problem is that I use two different router ABIs?

Please help me to understand the problem! Thanks in advanse!

I tried to change ABI, router address. Also I tried to use Uniswap V2 router with function swapExactTokensForTokens.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to swap USDC to any token on uniswap router v3 with ethers.js on
> frontend.

you cannot swap USDC with any kind token. you need to have pool pair contract. for example ETH/USD, you have to find the pool address for WETH/USDC and create a pool contract. `WETH` is `ERC20` version of `ETH`

you need to get the pool address and create a pool contract to get the immutables.

```
const poolContract = new ethers.Contract(
    poolAddress,
    IUniswapV3PoolABI,
    provider
  );
```

this is what you set as the first params

```
tokenIn: immutables.token1,
tokenOut: immutables.token0,
```

Then you have to have a swap router contract

```
const swapRouterContract = new ethers.Contract(
    swapRouterAddress,
    SwapRouterABI,
    provider
  );
```

the way how you created the swap router contract is wrong

```
const UniswapContract= new ethers.Contract(swapRouterAddress, ERC20ABI2, provider);
```

you are passing `ERC20ABI2` here. this should be `SwapRouterABI`. `ERC20ABI2` is used to construct the `USDC` token contract and other token contract that you are going to swap. Because eventually, you are swapping two `ERC20` contracts

If you need to swap `ERC20` tokens, first you have to allow the swap amount, so you have to call `approve` method of token contracts that you construct. you need to allow Uniswap to withdraw money from token contracts.

Finally you call the contract function

```
dd=await UniswapContract
     // maybe you should have const signer= await provider.getSigner()
    .connect(provider.getSigner())
    .exactInputSingle(params)
```